# Inequality involving e to some power x

Tags: inequality

$e^x-5ex>0$, how can I solve for the value of $x$?

I know the basics of logarithms, but I just cannot combine or simplify the $x$ or solve for $x$.

Comment: It is not possible to do it anallitycally with elementary functions. Perhaps with $W$-Lambert function.

Comment: Check wolfram-alpha on this one: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ex-5ex%3E0 You need W-Lambert functions for a full solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $$f(x)=e^x-5e x$$ $$f'(x)=e^x-5e$$ $$f''(x)=e^x >0$$ The first derivative cancels at $x_*=1+\log(5)$.

For this value $$f(x_*)=-5e\log(5)<0$$ which is a minimum which means that $f(x)=0$ has two roots.

So, $e^x >5ex$ will hold outside the range of the solutions of $f(x)=0$. As said in comments, they express in terms of Lambert function
$$x_1=-W\left(-\frac{1}{5 e}\right)\approx 0.0796782$$
$$x_2=-W\left(-1,-\frac{1}{5 e}\right)\approx 3.99431$$